# Animation: How to affect the mouseOver() image

Tags: javascript, html, css, onmouseover

In the code below, I was able to effect changes on the image/gif which I got a source for by means of CSS , making it a particular size or shape.
However, I could'nt effect any change for the image that will be shown when I mouseOver. It gives me the default size and shape.
I need to know a way I will carry out a change on it as well

```
<a class="newimg" href="C:\Users\Ak.Dell-PC\Desktop\Sublime Text 3\A.html" target="_blank">
    <img src="C:\Users\Ak.Dell-PC\Desktop\Sublime Text 3\img\9610-Flowers-In-The-Wind.gif"  alt="Visit new page!" border="1" name="flowers" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()"> 
</a>
```

```
a.newimg{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid orange;   
}
```

```
function mouseOver() {
    document.flowers.src="C:/Users/Ak.Dell-PC/Desktop/Sublime Text 3/img/IMG-20190112-WA0010.jpg";
}

function mouseOut() {
    document.flowers.src="C:/Users/Ak.Dell-PC/Desktop/Sublime Text 3/img/9610-Flowers-In-The-Wind.gif";
```

Comment: use css hover to change the CSS?

Comment: you shouldnt use absolute "local" path in your html/css/js. Beside that, you never controlled that image. You are styling the class `newimg`

Comment: [Without any javascript or jquery](https://jsfiddle.net/sk91Lyet/)

Comment: You don't need any JS.

Comment: Alright... I will effect these changes immediately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use css :hover so you can alter they styles.

```js
function mouseOver() {
  document.flowers.src = "http://placekitten.com/100/100";
}

function mouseOut() {
  document.flowers.src = "http://placekitten.com/200/300";
}
```

```css
a.newimg img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

a.newimg:hover img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<a class="newimg" href="#" target="_blank">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="Visit new page!" border="1" name="flowers" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">
</a>
```

And altering the images without any JavaScript

```css
a.newimg img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

a.newimg img:first-child {
  display: inline;
}

a.newimg img:last-child {
  display: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

a.newimg:hover img:first-child {
  display: none;
}

a.newimg:hover img:last-child {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<a class="newimg" href="#" target="_blank">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="Visit new page!" border="1" name="flowers">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="Visit new page!" border="1" name="flowers">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the functions in JS but you haven't added any event Listeners in your Javascript scripts. You need to add `document.getElementById('img').addEventListener()` and then pass the event and the corresponding function that you want to be invoked.

You can do it as follows -

```js
function mouseOver() {
  document.flowers.src = "https://live.staticflickr.com/2912/13981352255_fc59cfdba2_b.jpg";
}

function mouseOut() {
  document.flowers.src = "https://live.staticflickr.com/4561/38054606355_26429c884f_b.jpg";
}

document.getElementById('img').addEventListener('mouseOver', mouseOver)

document.getElementById('img').addEventListener('mouseOut', mouseOut)
```

```css
a.newimg {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<a class="newimg" href="C:\Users\Ak.Dell-PC\Desktop\Sublime Text 3\A.html" target="_blank">
  <img id='img' src="https://live.staticflickr.com/4561/38054606355_26429c884f_b.jpg" alt="Visit new page!" border="1" name="flowers" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">
</a>
```

I have changed the image URLs for demo, but you get the point of how to do it. You had defined the functions correctly, just not tied them with eventListeners